# How to copy a directory with only specified type of files?

Tags: command-line, files, file-copy

I got a git directory with plenty of python files(and some special file like .git).
I'd like to copy only these python files to another directory with the directory structure unchanged.

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will receive in `destination_dir` files with full path from `/`

```
find /path/git_directory -type f -iname "*.py" \
                         -exec cp --parents -t /path/destination_dir {} +
```

Other solution is `rsync`

```
rsync -Rr --prune-empty-dirs \
      --include="*.py" \
      --include="**/" \
      --exclude="*" \
      /path/git_directory /path/destination_dir
```